# remove leading and traling <br> from a string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have `<br>` inserted into a string using some logic in typescript.
I wanted to remove the `<br>`  at the begining and end of the string. Others should remain as it.
What is the best way to achieve?

I achieved it using `mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf('<br>'),mystring.lastIndexOf('<br>'))`

Want to know if its the optimum way of doing this.

Its a little more complicated.. Should replace all the 
 in the starting of the string and ending of the string.

```
<br><br>hello<br>user<br><br><br> should return hello<br>user
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? I'd expect a regular expression like `mystring.replace(/^<br>|<br>$/g,'')` should work. However you ***must*** also read [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Also see [*regexp101.com*](https://regex101.com).

Comment: I added what i wrote.Can you plz explain this?

Comment: @jocket mmm your code would break if `mystring` does not end with a `<br>`, because you'd end up remove whatever comes after the last `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly that, you can use this (confirmed locally),

```
mystring.replace(/(^(<br>)+)|((<br>)+$)/g, '')
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more info. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no need for the replace function, `''` is sufficient, more compatible and likely very much faster.

Comment: yeah makes sense, I was initially skeptical of it to work only for all the matches within if provided as a replacement function. Should've tried the string type too. Thanks for pointing it out.